# Getting an error on Discord JS "cannot read property of 'content' undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

CODE IS BELOW
I have a simple discord bot and added a message file under events--guild

````
    module.exports = (Discord, client, message) => {
    const prefix = '!';
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const command = client.commands.get(cmd);

    if(command) commmand.execute(client, message, args, Discord);
 }

```
Just Incase You need it here is my main file
```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.events = new Discord.Collection();


['command_handler', 'event_handler'].forEach(handler =>{;
    require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client, Discord)
})

 

 
client.login('My Token');
````

```
full error below
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined
    at Object.module.exports (E:\Software\Discord Bots\BombBot\events\guild\message.js:3:17)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (E:\Software\Discord Bots\BombBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (E:\Software\Discord Bots\BombBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (E:\Software\Discord Bots\BombBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (E:\Software\Discord Bots\BombBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (E:\Software\Discord Bots\BombBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (E:\Software\Discord Bots\BombBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

About: this discord bot is a simple bot that I am trying do with a command and event handler as I am new to discord js and not to javascript, I tried to see if there was a few issues, but couldn't find any. The debug window can't help either because its a value/variable that shows as undefined but is defined above.
as I am a bit new I used the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sihf7B8D4Y8 and rewrote the code multiple times. If you have an idea please tell me before I rewrite it again.

```
The Debugger is below
```

```
 E:\Software\node JS\node.exe .\index.js
BOT Is ONLINE
                                                          events/client/ready.js:4
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined
No debugger available, can not send 'variables'
Process exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to determine the origin of the error based on the info you provided.

The message content is not guaranteed. Messages from other bots that are embeds have no content, thus it's `undefined`. To fix this, add [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) in your condition:

```
if(!message.content?.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
```

If that doesn't work, that *probably* means your *message* object is not Discord Message at all. Make sure you pass the arguments to your function correctly.